# Best place to install antivirus with docker

Tags: linux, docker, antivirus

Currently I'm building some base images to use as docker hosts and I'm unsure where is the best place to run the antivirus.

Is it best to run on just the host or would it be best to base our new containers off a docker image that has antivirus baked into it?

I can see pros and cons for both hence the question.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best place would be a separate container with privileges and access to /var/lib/docker so it can scan all the other images/containers for malware.

Comment: Would this mean that the container would be able to scan the host O/S as well?

Comment: Depending on how you mount your volume. If you only mount `/var/lib/docker`, then no, it will only access the images and containers from the host, if you mount `/` then yes, it would have access to the host os as well.